# dart: unnecessary_null_comparision

Tags: dart, dart-analyzer

For the following code:

```
bool assertTest(int? n1, int? n2) {
  return (n1 == null) || (n1 != null && n2 != null);
}
```

there is a warning at `n1 != null`  saying `The operand can't be null, so the condition is always true.`
Why does this warning show up? n1 is obviously nullable.

Comment: Because if n1 is null the first part of your OR would be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boolean operation are lazy, it means that if you evaluate `a || b` and `a` is `true`, then `b` is not even evaluated.

In your case, if `b = (n1 != null && n2 != null)` is evaluated, it means `a = (n1 == null) = false`, which means `n1 != null` so the check `n1 != null` will always be true.

Comment: Hi! Thank you, it makes sense. I changed the order in which the two expressions are arranged and the warning vanished.

Comment: You should just remove the redundant comparison instead of changing the order: `return n1 == null || n2 != null;`.